# Why the scatter plot is not showing inside pairplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, scatter-plot

[image]

```
sns.pairplot(advertising, x_vars=['TV', 'Newspaper', 'Radio'], y_vars='Sales',size=4, aspect=1, kind='scatter')
plt.show()
```

here when i am calling the pairplot function it is not showing the first plot, if you change the sequence of x_vars then again it wont show the first plot.

But you can see it individually, How can i see all of them in a single pairplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug/feature introduced in seaborn v.0.11.0](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2260).

The workaround it to pass `diag_kind=None` to `pairplot`